# printing \78 gives beep-tone in console

Tags: python, windows

Why does the following code make my machine do a beep-tone?

```
print '\78'
```

I have tested it in the interactive interpreter and running a script in the command-line. I have also tested it in an embedded environment and it does not invoke a beep there.

Comment: It should work with just "\7"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It interprets `\7` as the *octal* escape, so it's BEL with ASCII code 7. This is a character that, when printed on a terminal, rings a bell. Yes, a literal bell in ancient times with teletypes (and even some terminals). Since we pride ourselves in not letting 1960s technology go to waste every terminal emulator has the same capability of making a sound at the sight of a character. Why it doesn't work in the embedded environment: Well, it's probably no terminal emulator you're having there.

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html) says that *“As in Standard C, up to three octal digits are accepted.”* Since `8` is no valid octal digit it stops with `\7`.

If you want the literal string `\78`, prefix an `r`:

```
print r'\78'
```

If you want the character `0x78` (`x`), then add an `x`:

```
print '\x78'
```

If you ask me, though, any octal niceties should be banned from programming languages unless when inventing new escape codes for them, e.g. `\o123` for strings or `0o153` for literals. The two conventions carried over from C here into countless programming languages just because it takes no effort to do so is in my humble opinion misguided and stupid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I want the character at ordinal number `78`? I.e. `chr(78)` but within string literals?

Comment: There is no built-in escape for this. You'd have to convert to hexadecimal (yes, I leave out the octal option here on purpose): '\x4e'. Or just use `'N'` to avoid all that character escaping stuff.

Comment: Using the hexadecimal escaping is a possible option, so I will use it. The characters I need to enter here are not *all* representable by characters on the keyboard. Something like `\o78` would be quite nice.. ^^